# React - kendo-ui styles module failed to parse - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, webpack, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need to import default Kendo-ui template styles from this site https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/styling/.

When it trying to load styles, it throws `NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Module parse failed: "project folder"\node_modules\@progress\kendo-theme-default\dist\all.css Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

Here is my layout.ts file where I want to import style template

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavMenu } from './NavMenu';
import "@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css";

export class Layout extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <div className='container-fluid'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-sm-3'>
                    <NavMenu />
                </div>
                <div className='col-sm-9'>
                    { this.props.children }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

webpack.config looks like this, its default configuration from auto generated react-redux asp.net project

```
    const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const merge = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);

    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const sharedConfig = () => ({
        stats: { modules: false },
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.tsx?$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true' },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
    });

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig(), {
        entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot-client.tsx' },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.css$/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' }) }
            ]
        },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new ExtractTextPlugin('site.css'),
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    });

    // Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig(), {
        resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
        entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot-server.tsx' },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./ClientApp/dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
                sourceType: 'commonjs2',
                name: './vendor'
            })
        ],
        output: {
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
            path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
        },
        target: 'node',
        devtool: 'inline-source-map'
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
};
```

Comment: I can't tell you the reason but if you put 
```import '@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css';```
to boot-client.tsx then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the external `.css` files to work ( like `kendo-theme-default` coming from `node_modules` ), a [`postcss-loader`](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader) is required.